# Java: Safely typecast a Clone of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, clone

I would like to make a clone of my arraylist by this code:

```
ArrayList<String> _names;

ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) _names.clone();
```

As far as I know, nothing special. My compiler however, gives the following warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<String>

Does anybody know a cleaner solution that does not give me a warning?

Comment: Casting to `ArrayList<?>` will not give this warning.  Do you need it to be an `ArrayList<String>`?  Can you call `toString` on the resulting elements instead?

Comment: for similar cases I have "unchecked" disabled by default :)

Comment: @ finnw: I need it for other types than just strings as well
@ bestsss: i like the solution of cadrian better :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
names = new ArrayList<String>(_names);
```

Or use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`